# SQL Replace String NULL with a NULL Value

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a database table that has a string value that literally says "NULL", it's not an actual `NULL` value, it's literally a string that says "NULL" (without the ").

I want to replace this the string value "NULL" with an actual `null` value.

This is what I tried to use but it replaces the entire column with `NULL` values, even when the string value isn't "NULL".

```
replace([col_1],'NULL',NULL) as [col_1]
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Not sure how much clearer I can make this. What isn't clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do this, instead of using the replace function, I used a case statement.

```
case
     when [col_1] = 'NULL' then NULL
     else [col_1]
     end as [col_1]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`NullIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) looks suitable:

```
select Col, NullIf( Col, 'NULL' ) as NullifiedCol
  from ( values ( '' ), ( 'Hello' ), ( 'NULL' ), ( 'Mmm, NULLBerries!' ) ) as Ph( Col );
```

As for the result you are seeing, from [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types): "Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL."